# remove element from list without removing all duplicates

Tags: prolog

i want remove elements from a list but if i do this:

```
deletelist([3,1,2,3,4], [3], [3,1,2,4])
```

how remove only a 3 and not get this answer:

```
deletelist([3,1,2,3,4], [3], [1,2,4])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to leave only unique values in list ?

Comment: yes i want remove a only a [3] and not all occurrence of 3.. NB i use Gprolog..

Comment: I've wrote conversion of `list to set` for GNU prolog. See if it helps...

Answer (score 2):

[select](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3)/3 it's an useful builtin, frequently used to `generate and test`, and you can use to delete an element:

```
?- select(3,[3,1,2,3,4],L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
L = [3, 1, 2, 4] ;
false.
```

each call removes a match, then you can control the desired behaviour

**edit**

to delete all elements from the second list:

```
deletelist(L, [], L).
deletelist(With, [D|Ds], Without) :-
    select(D, With, WithoutD),
    deletelist(WithoutD, Ds, Without).
```

Note that this will fail if any of elements to be deleted will not be found in list. To avoid this, apply a 'if .. then .. else ..'

```
deletelist(L, [], L).
deletelist(With, [D|Ds], Without) :-
    (  select(D, With, WithoutD)
    -> deletelist(WithoutD, Ds, Without)
    ;  deletelist(With, Ds, Without)
    ).
```

Now deletelist/3 will not enumerate all possible deletions. It commits to the first found. To resume the initial behaviour, that give on bactracking all different deletions, a less efficient procedure is required:

```
deletelist(L, [], L).
deletelist(With, [D|Ds], Without) :-
    select(D, With, WithoutD),
    deletelist(WithoutD, Ds, Without).
deletelist(With, [D|Ds], Without) :-
    \+ select(D, With, _),
    deletelist(With, Ds, Without).
```

Comment: ok but i want ricorsive select and i write this:       delric([],_,_).
delric([T|Cr],X,L) :- select(T,X,L), delric(Cr,L,L). but if i write delric([1,2,3],[2,3],R) i have no..

Comment: see my edit. When you detail better the requested behaviour, you get more choices...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just unique values in list - use function [list_to_set/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=list_to_set%2F2):

`list_to_set([3,1,2,3,4],X)` gives `X = [3, 1, 2, 4].`

**EDIT:**

So `gnu prolog` doesn't have built-in predicate `list_to_set`. You have to write it yourself.
For this you must define *set* concept. What is `set of list` ? Set should have these attributes:

- Set size must be less or equal to List size.
- All members of Set must be members of List.
- All members of List must be members of Set.
- Set must not contain duplicated values.

Based on these assumptions you can write `set_from_list` predicate like this:

```
elem_unique(Elem, List) :-
  delete(List, Elem, ListWithoutElem),
  length(List, OrgLength),
  length(ListWithoutElem, DelLength),
  DelLength + 1 =:= OrgLength.

nth_elem_isUnique(N, List) :-
  nth1(N, List, Elem),
  elem_unique(Elem, List).

nth_elemOfList1_isMemberOfList2(N, List1, List2) :-
  nth1(N, List1, Elem),
  member(Elem, List2).

elements_from_nth_areUnique(N, List) :-
  (length(List, Len),
  N > Len)    %stoping condition for recursion
  ;
  (nth_elem_isUnique(N, List),
  M is N + 1,
  elements_from_nth_areUnique(M, List)   %recursion part
  ).

listIsUnique(List) :-
  elements_from_nth_areUnique(1, List).

elements_from_nth_inList1_areMembersOfList2(N, List1, List2) :-
  (length(List1, Len),
  N > Len)    %stoping condition for recursion
  ;
  (nth_elemOfList1_isMemberOfList2(N, List1, List2),
  M is N + 1,
  elements_from_nth_inList1_areMembersOfList2(M, List1, List2)  %recursion part
  ).

list2containsList1(List1, List2) :-
  elements_from_nth_inList1_areMembersOfList2(1, List1, List2).

set_from_list(Set, List) :-
  length(Set, LenSet),
  length(List, LenList),
  LenSet =< LenList,
  list2containsList1(List, Set),
  list2containsList1(Set, List),
  listIsUnique(Set),
  !.
```

So after calling `set_from_list(Set, [3,1,2,3,4])` you will get `Set = [3,1,2,4]`.